# Apache/mod_rewrite/UserDir RewriteBase depending on UserDir/domain access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a Joomla installation. I would like to enable search-engine-friendly links and access the site from both the IP address, i.e. `1.2.3.4/~myuser/...` using UserDir and from the domain, i.e. `foo.com/...`.

The problem is that currently any URLs will give 404's except the index page.

I believe this is because I need to `RewriteBase /~user/` in my `.htaccess` file.

I can't do this because I also want to access it from the domain, where I would need to use `RewriteBase /` instead.

What are alternatives?

---

Additionally, it would be nice if I could find a generic solution. I'm running quite a few users on my server which would all like a 'blanket fix'.

Thanks.

---

Current `.htaccess`:

```
##
# @package              Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license              GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
# Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Provide your current .htaccess

Comment: Ok good but how is `http://1.2.3.4/~myuser/` SEO friendly?

Comment: It needs to act the same as the domain for testing purposes, setting up links, etc. The actual URLs generated are like `foo/bar/article.html`, standard Joomla rewriting.

Comment: Well you cannot use `RewriteBase /` if serving content from `/~myuser/` What's wrong with using `RewriteBase /~muysers/`

Comment: It won't work on the domain.

Comment: Would this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically