# Set RewriteBase to the current folder path dynamically

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any way to set RewriteBase to the path current folder (the folder which the .htaccess file is in) relative to the host root?

I have a CMS and if I move it to the directory in my host it does not work unless I set the RewriteBase to the path of directory relative to the root of host. I would like my CMS to work with only copy and paste, without changing any code in htaccess.

### Update:

For example:

```
webroot

 - sub_directory
 - cms
 - .htaccess
```

in this case I should write in the htaccess: `RewriteBase /`

and if I move the htaccess inside sub_directory I should change RewriteBase to:

`RewriteBase /sub_directory/`

So I want something like

`RewriteBase /%{current_folder}/`

Comment: That is relative to the Document Root?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is one way one can grab the `RewriteBase` in an environment variable which you can then use in your other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

Then you can use `%{ENV:BASE}` in your rules to denote `RewriteBase`, i.e.:

```
#redirect in-existent files/calls to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

#### Explanation:

This rule works by comparing the `REQUEST_URI` to the URL path that `RewriteRule` sees, which is the `REQUEST_URI` with the leading `RewriteBase` stripped away.  The difference is the `RewriteBase` and is put into `%{ENV:BASE}`.

- In a `RewriteCond`, the LHS (test string) can use back-reference variables e.g. `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` etc but RHS side i.e. condition string **cannot use** these `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` variables.
- Inside the RHS condition part only back-reference we can use are **internal back-references** i.e. the groups we have captured in this condition itself. They are denoted by `\1`, `\2` etc.
- In the `RewriteCond` first captured group is `(.*?/)`. It will be represented by internal back-reference `\1`.
- As you can make out that this rule is basically finding `RewriteBase` dynamically by comparing `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1`. An example of `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/directory/foobar.php` and example of `$1` for same example URI will be `foobar.php`. `^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$` is putting the difference in 1st captured group `%1` or `\1`. For our example it will populate `%1` and `\1` with the value `/directory/` which is used later in setting up env variable `%{ENV:BASE}` in `E=BASE:%1`.

Comment: Can these two commands be altered so that they will match URLs that contain multiple forward slashes? For example this will not work: /directory/a///b/c/ (note the 3 slashes after a)

Comment: Yes using a redirect rule all multiple slashes should be trimmed to single `/` first.

Comment: Today, more than five years later you may have saved my sanity. Thank you! This started to devour my soul!

Answer (score 15):

The accepted solution did not work for me, I think, but this did: https://web.archive.org/web/20180401034514/http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/8/Using-mod_rewrite-in-.htaccess-files-without-knowing-the-RewriteBase.html

Long story short:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Man, you saved my life, this works 100% and its short unlike the upper. If I could give my thumbs.

Comment: I have changed the link to use archive.org . For future proofing: https://www.castledragmire.com/misc/HTAccessPost.png

Answer (score 5):

Building on [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063276) and [Jon Lin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027742), here's what I just came up with for myself (haven't used this in production nor tested this extensively yet).

Let's use this example URL, where .htaccess is in current_folder:

`http://localhost/path_to/current_folder/misc/subdir/file.xyz`

Filesystem: `/var/www/webroot/path_to/current_folder/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBPATH} ^$  # Check if variable is empty. If it is, process the next rule to set it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [ENV=SUBPATH:$1]
# SUBPATH is set to 'misc/subdir/file.xyz'

RewriteCond %{ENV:CWD} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBPATH}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)::(.*?)\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=CWD:%2]
# CWD is set to '/path_to/current_folder/'

RewriteCond %{ENV:FILENAME} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=FILENAME:%1]
# FILENAME is set to 'file.xyz'

# Check if /var/www/webroot/path_to/current_folder/misc/subdir/file.xyz exists.
# -f checks if a file exists, -d checks for a directory.
# If it exists, rewrite to /path_to/current_folder/misc/subdir/file.xyz and stop processing rules.
RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBPATH} ^.+$  # Ensure SUBPATH is not empty
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:SUBPATH} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:SUBPATH} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:SUBPATH} [END]

# Check if /var/www/webroot/path_to/current_folder/file.xyz exists.
# If it exists, rewrite to /path_to/current_folder/file.xyz and stop processing rules.
RewriteCond %{ENV:FILENAME} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}%{ENV:FILENAME} [END]

# Else, rewrite to /path_to/current_folder/index.html and stop processing rules.
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.html [END]
```

You can view the details of what's happening for yourself by using `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` in your `httpd.conf` in apache, and then looking in your `error.log`.

Here's a bit more clarification on the following two lines, which I'd still found a bit confusing.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBPATH}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)::(.*?)\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=CWD:%2]
```

First off, the double colon `::` is not an operator of any sort; it's just an arbitrary delimiter. The `RewriteCond` expands TestString `%{ENV:SUBPATH}::%{REQUEST_URI}` to the following:

`misc/subdir/file.xyz::/path_to/current_folder/misc/subdir/file.xyz`

Then our CondPattern `^(.*)::(.*?)\1$`:

1. `^(.*)::` matches `misc/subdir/file.xyz::`
2. `\1` is the first capture group, `misc/subdir/file.xyz`
3. `(.*?)\1$` becomes `(.*?)misc/subdir/file.xyz$`
4. Thus, our second capture group `(.*?)` matches the remaining `/path_to/current_folder/`

And our `RewriteRule` sets `CWD` to `%2`, which is the second capture group of CondPattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `RewriteBase`  command in htaccess, you might comment that and then it will be automatically resolved to that directory.