# Apache Alias For External Directory And All Sub Directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias

I want to add a alias for my website. So that website.com/alias will go to a folder outside of the root folder. This folder contains a different website so i want to be able to treat this alias as if it were a subdomain.

```
AliasMatch  ^/subdir1/(.*)$ /var/www/otherfolder/subdir1/$1
```

I was hoping this would match all calls, so that website.com/subdir1/css/style.css would also be a valid path, but all of these are returning 404 errors.

How can i make the alias match a wildcard so that the entry will cover all subdirectories in the alias folder. I want to be able to do this on the apache level rather than having to do it within the .htaccess file because things are already quite complicated there so i want to bypass it if possible.

Comment: Technically any subdirectory is NOT considered a subdomain no matter where it points to. It is in fact, a subdirectory. A subdomain would be subdomain.example.com where www.example.com is the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a base URL. "/" was not correctly working as a base url. Instead i was able to solve it based on the answer here.

[Set RewriteBase to the current folder path dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

The above was enough to solve the problem based on the post i have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases will work if you have mod_alias.so http module loaded. You need to edit httpd.conf configuration file and add below line and restart httpd.

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
```

Comment: The alias already works it just isn't picking up sub directories within the alias

Comment: Did you check permissions on directories? And also did you observe any specific error in /var/log/httpd/error_log ?

Comment: the error log just says it cant find files. for some reason all file paths are being stripped of the subdirectory. if i go to website.com/subdir/css it brings me to website.com/css