# Remove index.php From Sub directory websites URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I am currently in the process of moving a large number of subdomain websites to become sub directory websites. e.g. site1.website.com => website.com/site1. All of these sites use the same code in the same directory. The code will read the site name and load the correct database if it exists. So i have the following alias formatting for all sites.

```
Alias  /site1 /var/www/laravel/public
```

Without needing to explain too much, laravel is an MVC framework and index.php is the only file that i need to route traffic through. Because of this all of the URLS need to have index.php as a prefix, but this is really ugly and i cant seem to get rid of it.

I tried the following which worked when the website was a subdomain, but it doesnt work now. When i use this code website.com/site1/login will redirect to website.com/login.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

All websites are dynamic so i dont want to hardcode a rule for every single website. Is there a way i can handle this?

Comment: Can you [try this](http://sysaxiom.com/remove-publicindex-php-from-your-laravel-project-in-two-steps/) ?

Comment: this kind of worked. The urls arent redirecting to the main website, but its still giving a 404 error. The requested URL /site1/login was not found on this server.

Comment: You have regular `routes.php` or dealing something dynamic in it ?

Comment: just regular routes.php. The only thing that i have dynamic is the database connection. everything else worked just fine when it was a subdomain

Comment: You have `.htaccess` in your `root` or `home` folder  ?

Comment: its currently in the public folder. i tried to move it out to the root as per the guide you linked above, but normally it has been located in the public folder

Comment: Inside the `.htaccess` for your subdomain that you try, can you add this in the top of your `.htaccess` ? `RewriteEngine Off`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a RewriteBase for the new folder, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: awesome! this worked. Do you know if its possible to do this dynamically? I have a lot of subdomains and i will be adding more in the future so it would be nice if i didnt have to add a new one each time.

Comment: I misread your question before. I'm not really use why `RewriteBase /` wouldn't work. Surely Laravel will deal with the directories for you?

Comment: for some reason when i set RewriteBase / it will just display the home page from the main website. Your above code has worked perfectly, its just a lot of manual code to write so if i could set the base dynamically it would be perfect. i have root access to the server so i can change anything i need to in apaches conf files

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically does this do it?

Comment: actually this worked! RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L] . i removed the reqwritebase completely

Answer (score 0):

you can manage connection from **laravel\config\database.php** for your each site.

then you can set all sub domain will be point on one location, now you need to update update just **database.php**  when you add new website.

Comment: the database isnt the issue its index.php in the url. the database connections are working fine