# Use regex in Rewrite base htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

I am looking for the way I can use `Rewrite Base` in htaccess with regular expression.

I have now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/v1

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

But I need to have base url as `/api/v1 and /api/v2` maybe `/api/v3` in the future

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this. Think about it. In fact it should be better having a new direcory and rewritten from these new directories the versions of yourt API.

Comment: I need to do this in the same director that's why I am asking

Comment: I promise you. It'll become very messy having more than one version in one directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set RewriteBase to the current folder path dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on RewriteBase.

If /api/vX is in the URL that got you to this file, just extract it with a rewritecond looking at REQUEST_URI and never make a relative substituton in a rewriterule.