# Redirect not working when app not in root

Tags: php, .htaccess

I set up .htaccess file to redirect to the _install folder if the app is just downloaded.

The problem I'm having is if the App was uploaded to a folder other than the root folder, the redirection break. It tries to go to the root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
#allow installation
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_install

#redirect to _install if vendor does not exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendor !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /_install [L,redirect=302]

#start application if vendor exists
#allow installation to continue
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_install
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendor -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

so if the App is in the folder `/project` it redirects to `/_install` instead of `/project/_install`.

How do I make sure no matter what folder the App is, it will take everything from that folder?

Comment: Well you can hardly expect this to be “flexible” in this regard, if you are checking absolute paths using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically in env variable BASE
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

#allow installation
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_install [NC]
#redirect to _install if vendor does not exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}vendor !-d 
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}_install [L,R=302]

#start application if vendor exists
#allow installation to continue
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_install
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}vendor -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This work perfectly! Where do I learn more about this? Is there a documentation on this?

Comment: Check this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063276/548225 I have provided detailed explanation there.